# Remove two from a list of checkboxes selected using Jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Using this function

```
function (container, none, all) {
    this.checkboxes = $("input[name *='" +  container + "']");
    this.none = $("input[name *='" + none + "']");
    this.all = $("input[name *='" + all + "']");
};
```

I'm selecting a list of checkboxes and storing them in "checkboxes", and at the same time selecting one which I will use for selecting all and another that will use for deselecting all (strage enough "all" and "none").

Both of these "all" and "none" are in the initial list and I would like to remove them from there, ideally without adding classes to them (they are  rendered using an .NET MVC Editor Template I wouldn't like to fiddle with) just using that names I pass to the function as parameter if possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) filter to remove those items - you have to rearrange the code also as given below for easy access

```
function (container, none, all) {
    this.none = $("input[name *='" + none + "']");
    this.all = $("input[name *='" + all + "']");
    this.checkboxes = $("input[name *='" + container + "']").not(this.none).not(this.all);
};
```